# Renderizando uma imagem do tipo blob com PHP + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagem

Minha imagem está salva no banco de dados. Quando pego ela e dou um dd ela retorna que é um stream resource, entao estou usando o seguinte codigo para pegar o content dela:

`stream_get_contents($data['img'])`

E ele retorna o contents dessa imagem em base64, acredito eu, pois retorna várias letras e numeros juntos.

Queria saber como posso renderizar essa imagem

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110907/how-to-decode-a-base64-string-gif-into-image-in-php-html) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262098/displaying-a-base64-images-from-a-database-via-php). Acredito que estas respostas podem te ajudar

Comment: ou tente assim: `
$contents = stream_get_contents($data['img']);
$base64 = 'data:image/PNG;base64,' . base64_encode($contents);
echo "<img src=$base64 />" ;`

Comment: Eu tentei algo do tipo= return base64_decode(stream_get_contents($data['img']));
e apareceu: 
�PNG  IHDRRRo&�U1IDATx���1 �@��O�B!���½��=�K$�$K �%���D`I"�$�X�H,I$�$K �%���D`I"�$�X�H,I$�$K �%���D`I"�$�X�H,I$�$K �%���D`I"�$�X�H,I$�$K �%���D`I"�$�X�H,I$�$K �%���D`I"�$

preciso que retorne sem a tag <img> pois estou criando uma api

Comment: No caso, você vai recuperar esses dados via um link nas routes de API? Essa API vai ser consumida em PHP?

Comment: Não. A api é em php, a imagem está no banco, eu estou fazendo a api. Dei um select na imagem e agora quero retornar para criar um link do servidor com essa imagem renderizada. Uma aplicação em react vai consumir minha api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema usando a biblioteca do Intervention Image

```
 $img = Image::make(stream_get_contents($data['img']));
 return $img->response();
```